# implementation of size in standard containers

Tags: c++, stl

This is a purely theoretical question, I know that the standard containers interface are not likely to change now...

I read recently one of Herb Sutter "guru of the week" where he complained about the fact that empty() was implemented as a member function in `std::string`. I did not agree with all the arguments, because e.g. `std::list` would require a different implementation of the same function, as `size()` is O(n) and `empty()` is obviously O(1).

However, is there a reason why the standard specify that the empty() member function of (for instance) `std::string` is implemented as `"size () == 0"` instead of `"begin () == end ()"` ?

It seems to me that the latter allow the same O(1) implementation of the `empty()` function for all containers, and I can't think of any drawback. Is it less efficient?

Thanks,

N.G.

Comment: I would like a link to the GotW where Herb said this. Because it doesn't make sense for `size` to not be a member of the container. I want to see the context of the statement. And I couldn't find it with Google.

Comment: Guess you refer to this GotW http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm

Comment: There's a GOTW column (http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm) which discusses whether or not `size` should be a member function - but it doesn't draw the conclusion that the question says it does.

Comment: I don't think there has to be a single `size` function. The free function could be overloaded for each type, as it is with the free `swap` function.

Comment: I think you misunderstood it, Herb suggests that `length` should not be a member function because `size` already is. That is, once you have `size`, and a standard definition of `length` that requires it's return value to be that of `size` there is no need for an extra member function.

Comment: The standard doesn't say that `std::string::empty` is *implemented* as `size() == 0`. It says that `std::string::empty` returns the value `size() == 0` . There's a subtle difference between those two. The standard never dictates the implementation. The implementation is free to do as it pleases as long as it keeps the same observable behaviour. In this case, `std::string` could say, keep a boolean member to return for `empty()` as long as it was kept up-to-date all the time. Yes, silly, but allowed.

Comment: Edited: I meant the "empty" member function and not "size".

Comment: `list::size()` shouldn't be O(n), as the container requirements state that `size()` should be constant complexity for all containers.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: I'm fairly certain that wasn't yet the case when Herb wrote that GotW.

Comment: @MSalters: no, the article also says "`size()` should run in constant time" in the paragraph that the OP disagrees with, and doesn't include efficiency in the arguments for/against `empty()` being a member.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard doesn't specify *exactly* how anything in the library is implemented. It merely specifies the meaning of something. So if `empty()` is true, then `size()` must also be 0. That doesn't mean that empty() *must* actually call `std::basic_string::size()` and compare it to 0. The spec is simply saying that if `empty()` returns true, then calling `size()` immediately after will return 0, and if `empty()` returned false, then calling `size()` immediately after will *not* return 0.

The spec could have said that its `begin()` would equal its `end()`, and it would force no implementations to change.

The inconsistency is most likely a consequence of the `std::basic_string` class having come from a different place from the rest of the STL containers during the development of C++98. That's why it has so many member functions for doing things that STL containers would typically do with algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

The specifications that `empty()` is to be equivalent to `size() == 0` is not to be taken literally. The code snippets only show the intent of the functions, not exactly how they are to be implemented.

I have this confirmed from committee members in another forum.

In your  example, it is also possible that `size()` is implemented as the equivalent of `end() - begin()`, so there might be no difference anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would be less efficient as string::end() usually is implemented as something like `return (_STRING_ITERATOR(_Myptr() + this->_Mysize));`

Thus, using size() == 0 reduces the need for an addition.

Comment: That is, assuming that `size()` is literally free. :)

Comment: An implementation would likely store one of size and an end_ptr and calculate the other. That makes it essentially free (at most one addition or subtraction).

Comment: @Viktor: It depends on the implementation, the string could be implemented in terms of three pointers: `_begin`, `_end` and `_end_of_capacity` rather than a pointer `_begin` and two sizes there isn't that much of a difference

Comment: @All: thats why i wrote, "usually is implemented"

Comment: This doesn't explain why the `empty()` member function of the containers is specified as having the semantics of `begin() == end()`. Why not take the same care to make the containers "more efficient"?

Comment: @R. Martinho: The non-string containers _do_ specify `empty()` that way. It's only `std::string` that doesn't.

Comment: @Nicol: Exactly my point. If this really is an issue of efficiency, why are containers different (i.e., "not efficient")?

Comment: R. Martinho Fernandes: Might be that size() is a more common operation on strings than end(), and vice verse for containers.

Comment: @Viktor - Another explanation is that the string section of the standard document was written by other people than the container section. Different parts of the library have totally different styles, because they were written at different times and by different people.

Answer (score 0):

Herb suggests making `length()` a non-member function implemented in terms of `size()`, and equivalently with `empty()`:

> What about length()? Easy, again -- it's defined to give the same result as size(). What's more, note that the other containers don't have length(), and it's there in the basic_string interface as a sort of "string thing", but by making it a nonmember suddenly we can consisently say "length()" about any container. Not too useful in this case because it's just a synonym for size(), I grant you, but a noteworthy point in the principle it illustrates -- making algorithms nonmembers immediately also makes them more widely useful and usable.

The reason for `size()` being a member function is that in most cases the implementations will cache the value for containers where it is expensive to calculate (i.e. for a list or a map, the number of contained elements is stored in the container itself to avoid having to walk the structure), to comply with the recommendation in the standard that `size` should be a `O(1)` operation (§23.1/5).

Comment: Doesn't really make sense, though. `.length` exists for compatibility with pre-standard (draft), non-STL implementations of `std::string`. A nonmember `length()` neither adds value over member `.size()` nor does it help with compatibility.

Comment: @MSalters: I agree with you, but the point of the whole article is that there are many functions in `std::basic_string<>` that should not be members, and I think he just used that as another example of member function that should not be (in this case the best approach would be to ditch it altogether IMHO)